# custom listview in widget

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, widget, dynamic-programming

it is possible to customize a listview in the widget?
I followed this tutorial: https://blogs.infinitesquare.com/posts/mobile/ajouter-des-widgets-a-vos-applications-android-xamarin

but I do not understand how they managed to customize the result and display it?

Furthermore,  I add lines in the listview dynamically.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your link throws an 404...

Comment: https://blogs.infinitesquare.com/posts/mobile/ajouter-des-widgets-a-vos-applications-android-xamarin

Comment: Hm, can you specify your question? It's impossible to read this as non-french..

Comment: is it possible to customize a listview in widget?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You'll have to be more specific about what you need clarified.

Comment: I need a widget with a listview where I add the data dynamically. I already have my layout that is done as well as the listview. I would like to customize the rows of a listview (the model is already done) I can not "assign" the model to the listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to customize the rows of a listview (the model is already done) I can not "assign" the model to the listview

In the tutorial your provide, they create a layout(Widget_EpisodeItem.axml) for their list row. And apply it in the GetViewAt() method. The Home_IncomingItem_Title and  Home_IncomingItem_EpisodeTitle should be the textview in the row. You could modify this method to custom your listview.

```
public RemoteViews GetViewAt(int position)
{
    var rV = new RemoteViews(_context.PackageName, 
               Resource.Layout.Widget_EpisodeItem); //The list row layout
    var data = _episodes[position];
    rV.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.Home_IncomingItem_Title, "titre");
 
    var ei = "2x04 : Nous à infinite square";
    rV.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.Home_IncomingItem_EpisodeTitle, ei);
 
    return remoteView;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but yet nothing appears in my widget.
As if it did not go through GetViewAt ().

Comment: @Choupi Do you set data to the widget? Could you provide your project?

Comment: In fact, I have before the listview a title (which is displayed well) then I have my listview and in another axml file I have my model with LinearLayout (can that block?). In the GetViewAt () I fill my rows template and in the onUpdate I declare an intent (context, widgetService) and make a setRemoteAdapter on the list with the intent .. but nothing is displayed

Comment: I found a working demo of custom listview in the widget on [GitHub](https://github.com/Nailik/AppWidgetListView). You could refer to it. I can't find the reason why yours widget not working without your code.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow this tutorial and see what happens. small question the template file must be absolutely in 'axml' or 'xml' format?

Comment: Both are ok. It's better to use axml

Comment: I just did exactly the tutorial you gave me but with my data, and it only shows me the empty view. I do not understand

Comment: If I put a Console.WriteLine in GetViewAt () .. it should be displayed?

Comment: Try  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("some text"); I have tested, it does display.

Comment: mmmh, either it does not go through GetViewAt () or it passes but does not show up in the output...

Comment: How do you set the data?

Comment: The tutorial on GitHub helped me a lot. Thanks